# How to convert an object to an array in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get some data with axios and then use the .map() function.
I'm getting this error back: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): items.map is not a function.

The data that I'm fetching comes as an object. I need to turn it into an array so that I can map through the data and display it.

How do I turn the object (fetched data) to an array, using async await syntax?

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets`)
      setItems(res.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  },[])
```

Comment: The error is on a line that is not in the code you have shared.

Comment: Please add the code where you used `map()` function and the structure of the `res`. (try a console log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `res.data.data`. usually, there are 2 levels of `data`